El significado de "auto rx"
¿qué significa “auto rx” en este enlace? La frase tiene que ver con oftalmología y parece que “rx” se refiere a “receta médica”.
Las partes relevantes del enlace son:

... datos del informe que le han hecho en el hospital los oftalmólogos a mi suegro ...
está ciego del ojo izquierdo, el ojo derecho le ha empeorado ...
Copio y pego lo que indica el informe para que no haya erratas por mi parte:
...
OI sc Amaurosis
Auto Rx
OD +1,25 3,00 x 107º
OI 0
...

¡Muchas gracias de antemano! Saludos ~

La palabra "auto" tiene un significado en español que no tiene en inglés.  Ver wikipedia automdicaciónÑ  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automedicaci%C3%B3n

El término no es de uso exclusivo en español, se usa también en el ámbito oftalmológico en inglés.
El símbolo ℞ (y no rx)
Primero en general, en medicina, la abreviatura latina ℞ significa receta médica en español o medical prescription en inglés y, por lo que he podido ver, se usa desde la antigua Roma. Si bien parece una R y una x, es un símbolo en si mismo, representado por el caracter Unicode U+211
Luego, el término Auto ℞, parece referirse a una prescripción obtenida a través de un autorrefractor (artículo enlazado en inglés).
La prescripción de lentes o anteojos generalmente toma la forma de:



Eye
SPH
CYL
Axis
Add




O.D






O.S







(He puesto intencionalmente en inglés los títulos de las columnas para no cometer el error de traducir algo incorrectamente, ya que no soy un profesional de la oftalmología).

O.D. Es la abreviatura de oculus dexter, el ojo derecho
O.S. Es la abreviatura de oculus sinister, el ojo izquierdo
Los datos de SPH (Sphere) usualmente tienen un signo + o -
Los datos del CYL (Cylinder) son numéricos
Los datos del Axis se dan en grados y están entre 0° y 180°

La salida típica de un autorrefractor es una prescripción de este tipo.
El texto que sigue a "Auto Rx" en el informe enlazado lo confirman:

Auto Rx
OD +1,25 3,00 x 107º

El hecho que tenga datos solo para el ojo derecho coincide con la descripción del paciente, que ha perdido ya la visión del ojo izquierdo y, por tanto, no hay datos para este en la prescripción.
Desconozco, sin embargo, entre las líneas que siguen, hasta dónde llega la prescripción, es decir, si los otros valores mostrados también vienen del auto-refractor o son ya otra parte del informe.
